# Poltergeist proxy not working

Tags: proxy, capybara, poltergeist

I am trying to use capybara-poltergeist with proxy to emulate a browser.

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'capybara/dsl'

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist_proxy do |app|
Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app,:js_errors => false,{ :phantomjs_options => ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--proxy-type=https','--proxy=112.124.46.186:80'] })
end
Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist_proxy
Capybara.default_wait_time = 90
Capybara.app_host = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk'
visit('/')
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error -

> /Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/poltergeist-1.5.0/lib/capyb
>   ara/poltergeist/web_socket_server.rb:87:in `rescue in send': Timed out waiting for response to {"name":"visit","args":["https://www.bbc.co.uk/"]}. It's possible  that this happened because something took a very long time (for example a page load was slow). If so, setting the Poltergeist :timeout option to a higher value  will help (see the docs for details). If increasing the timeout does not help, this is probably a bug in Poltergeist - please report it to the issue tracker. (Capybara::Poltergeist::TimeoutError)

I am not sure what mistake I am making. I know the syntax I am using is correct, based on a related query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278597/using-poltergeist-with-a-proxy), as well as mentioned at the github.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `https` is a valid proxy type (see https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference). Also, you can try adding `timeout: 180` to your driver options